# Multi tenant app that share data (Asp net mvc + Entity Framework + Sql Server)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, multi-tenant

I'm developing a multi tenant app architecture that is quite complex.

.

### **3 completly different kind of app**

Ther is no only one type of application used by many customers; ther are 3 different kind of applications.

APP A, APP B, APP C

.

### **Each APP is multitenant**

Each app has its customers.

APP A
- customer A1
- customer A2

APP B
- customer B1
- customer B2

APP C
- customer C1
- customer C2

.

### SHARED INFORMATIONS

Many informations are shared betwen the different apps

**"customer A1"** need to manipulate or only view data owned by **"customer C1"**

.

### **QUESTION**

Consider that i'm using Asp net mvc, EF, Sql Server.
Wich is the correct implementation?

One site and many Areas?
Create multiple sites?
Multiple db? Only one db? Filtering? Sql filtered view? ...

**Some application example?**

EDIT

and... Where to put the business logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you first build your own multi-tenant engineering stack (Framework) on top of .Net which will handle all the requirements of multi-tenancy in terms of tenant wise data isolation, support for horizontal scaling, filtering of views based on the tenant context and role of the user, tenant wise data model extension, tenant wise UI customization, enforcing access restrictions based on roles,  privileges and data scope - which could be different for different tenants etc.

The business logic can be built on top of this framework. This approach will provide your product a robust and strong engineering foundation.

The other alternative is to buy a ready to use multi-tenant engineering stack off the shelf, install it on Visual Studio and use it as a development template.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally in a multi-tenant server with a single app you want physically different databases for each tenant, rather than just a column specifying which tenant the data belongs too

But either way you have to ensure that **ALL** database functions use the correct database connection or tenant column key. That is the real issue

The way to make sure of this is to have only **ONE** function per app that makes this decision, and make sure all database functions fail if they have not called this function (directly, or indirectly as below)

e.g. With MVC in the global.asax AuthenticateRequest or BeginRequest function you can validate who the user is and then calculate which database connection they need to use or what tenant column key they must use in EVERY query for that request. This is then stored in a session variable etc

If you have three apps, I would make three separate sites. They can share common classes via a shared project. Life is generally easier if they can be deployed separately

Comment: Agree with the importance on maintaining tenant isolation with single gateways. Disagree that "physically different databases for each tenant" is the "ideal" solution. From a scale POV, it is usually not practical to have separate databases for multi-tenant apps who have thousands or millions of tenants. A single, or single set of DBs is needed so that the DB can be distributed or clustered. Multiple entry points in clustered environments is anarchy.

Comment: @cottsak That all depends on the intended data purpose and scale etc of your app. Not many people are dealing with thousands or millions of tenants, or even clustering. Where is your answer?

Comment: @TFD Didn't think this was an answer. Just my opinion.

Comment: "physically different databases for each tenant" is bad solution for this problem because each tenant need to share data with the other 2 kind of tenant.

Comment: @Bugeo How is that a problem? One app can read any amount of datasources. Not saying it is the best answer since I don't know your tenant count or DB size, but it is a very clean technique

Comment: @TFD the problem is not read from different datasource. The problem is "sharing". Another problem il query the same kind of data from multipel datasource. Suppose that App-A1 need to read all order from App-B1, AppB2...AppB200. this mean 200 query from 200 different datasources...

Comment: @Bugeo It would not be a problem. You data service layer just needs a "key" to identify which "datasource" (by key or connection) to use. They effectively all have the same cost to access. The challenge with multi-tenant is to ensure that ALL your code accesses the correct datasource every time, and that you can't accidentally write a function that by-passes this. To share data you need an extra function to check auhorisation to another datasource, and to return the key or connection to use instead of the default for that tenant

Answer (score 0):

This is a concrete answer, but just some some aspects you may consider when designing this.

With regards to shared information, I think the most important part here is to define the relationship between customers and the roles and rights each customer has with respect to other customers. The best approach is to start with is identifying what exactly can be done.

Example:

```
Read Only|cust1|cust2|cust3
---------+-----+-----+-----
customer1| 1   | 1   | 0
customer2| 0   | 1   | 0
customer3| 1   | 0   | 1

Write    |cust1|cust2|cust3
---------+-----+-----+-----
customer1| 1   | 1   | 0
customer2| 0   | 1   | 0
customer3| 0   | 0   | 1
```

So in the above, customer1 can read and write(update) customer2's data.

This being said, the main issue is model these relationships i.e. the shared information.  Using @TFD's suggestion, these relationships can be loaded into session for when a customer logs on along with the relevant tenant id's.

(Based on the information provide, my other inclination is that this may be a per application concern and not a customer only  concern. To illustrate this, replace the 'cust' values in the above tables with `App`.)

Create separate sites for each application since I am assuming that each application has a unique purpose although there is shared functionality.

Maybe  a different Config DB is needed if there are other cross data relationships. The DB would store all the tenant information (incl. relationships to other Apps) for each App.  The reason for this suggestion is that from what I can see, you have three separate multi-tenant apps independent of each other using a shared DB approach - but each App need to interact with another App on some level.
In terms of customers within the DB, I would then suggest that the 'Customers' table be confined to the Config DB. You can then have a content DB based on each applications requirements.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use PRISM with Sliverlight and MVVM design patten. PRISM is designed for such kind of composite application where each application is independent and can also communicate with each other via Events exposed by PRISM.

Answer (score -1):

You can have multiple approaches - since the app is data driven, it makes sense to build a database design that secures the data even in case of application bugs.

One way to do this is ensure that there are stored procs for accessing any tables and the security logic is built into the stored procedures. You can ensure that a different db username is used for each customer, and that this db user name is mapped against that tenant id in a mapping table. Then the stored procs can always have a check that the data being requested/modified is actually belonging to the tenant id mapped to the db user who is running the proc (by using context information).

Then you will need some way to ensure that the db connection created by the application uses only the corresponding username that maps to that tenant id. This means you need one more stored proc that gives you this information (with probably username/id as the input) and this stored proc should be executable through a common db username. Remember, this is the only stored proc that needs to have execution priveleges given to this common db user.

This might look like writing a bunch of extra code, but it really helps to know that your db will reject bad requests even due to application bugs. The only place you have be really, really careful is the place where you get the right tenant db username and password for that user id, and that should be quite possible.

Comment: If all access pass to the db through stored procedures may be possible to map the db with an ORM?

Comment: It is possible but not advisable - ORM treats your db like a dumb store, so when you have security logic built into the database, it makes more sense to directly call the SPs using Data access classes.

Comment: DB *should* be a dumb store. A database/data-store/persistence-store is exactly what it's name suggests - to store and persist data. It's not for logic of any kind. Logic, business or otherwise should go into the application. SPROCs are no safer than string-literals in your application. And like i said in TFD's answer, if your app will scale at some point you don't want to have thousands of DB users and complex security permissions. User the db as a drawer for data, nothing else. Your business and multi-tenant logic should be in the app.

Comment: ..yes, the logic to separate the persisted data from one tenant from the next will likely live in your data tier somewhere as this is not really a domain (business) concern but rather an infrastructure one.

Comment: @cottstak - this is more of a design choice than a generic rule. Just because non-relational dbs are good for scaling, we do not give up using relational dbs altogether. Similarly if someone does go for a relational database, I don't see any reason why not to secure the data and the database level itself. For eg. if you ever want to provide synchronization and happen to choose microsoft sync framework (which is by far the best choice in this case), let me know how you plan to build in security without using the database tier intelligently.

Comment: @Roopesh The way i see it it's all about getting the responsibilities right. Domain logic like business rules and app logic like user management and tenant management belong within the context of the application. Data persistence like replication, sync, and query performance (caching etc) belong with the data, in the database. I'm saying that i'd agree with using something like MSSQL Replication for Replication or DTC for Transactions because it's within their areas of responsibility. However, just because TSQL has the ability to put business logic in SPROCs, doesn't mean it belongs there.

Comment: @cottsak - again, I would say it matters.. on what kind of data you are holding. And what is easier to achieve. It is much easier to achieve tenant management within the database. This is also very important in an enterprise scenario when multiple applications might access the same data. The data owning team needs to ensure data security is achieved without relying on the application development team.

Comment: @Roopesh Ok. That's simply where we disagree then. I'm fundamentally opposed to data being treated as a separate entity to the app that consumes it. I'm not sure what a "data owning team" is but if i have a DB that my app uses, then no other connection need be made to that DB (sysadmin, backup, maintenance etc excluded) except the ones from my application. It should be the app's responsibility to maintain the persistence and integrity. If another app wants my data, it should ask it from my app, not the db. Having rogue connections reading (and god forbid writing) to my db is a no no.